# How do graphql subscriptions get data after being triggered by a mutation?

Tags: graphql

Does a GraphQL subscription get data from the arguments passed in to the mutation by the client, or does it get data that is returned by the mutation resolver?

If so, is it then necessary for a subscription and mutation that triggers it to have the same return Type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither. GraphQL `Subscription` and `Mutation` are separate operations. It depends on the server implementation on how the data is returned for a `Mutation` operation and a `Subscription` operation. GraphQL specifications do not mandate any such thing.

Although, it's kind of a common practice to have a `Subscription` operation that returns a result each time a particular `Mutation` operation occurs. Usually, this is handled in a server using PubSub functionality. But this is not a mandatory thing, and it doesn't have to do anything with the client side. It's completely a server-side implementation detail rather than a GraphQL-specific thing.

So, to answer your second question, no. It's not necessary until *you* (the backend developer) decide to do so.